# Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: meaning

I will not let people tattoo the inside of my skin .[image]

Comment: It’s unclear what ‘sense’ you’re referring to. Please [edit] to explain what you consider to be possibly nonsensical about the sentence, and why (in terms of sentence structure or grammar etc) it seems odd to you.

Comment: I want to say that I will not let people give me tattoos anymore, in way that is hard to remove.

Comment: It's grammatical, but it doesn't make logical sense in terms of common reality. It's highly unlikely that anybody would be in a position to tattoo the *inside* of your skin in the first place. I can only see that happening if somebody cuts you open for that purpose. (Tattoos are applied to the surface of your skin, but also extend below it due to their nature.) However, it could be said in a kind of joking way. So, it might be fine in the right context. I'd put it along the same lines as *I don't enjoy travelling through black holes.*

Answer (score 2):

The sentence makes sense in that it is grammatically correct. As for making sense in a meaningful way, it does too, if you can think metaphorically, or even just imagine the gory situation in which someone would have access to the inside of your skin.  We also have a saying, when someone "gets under your skin", it means that he or she is annoying you, making you very irritated or frustrated...
In this way, your sentence does strike a nerve, it makes one think that you have been hurt so much by people, who have violated your mental/physical boundaries, but you are sticking up for yourself and not allowing them to hurt, or in this case, mark or draw on you any further.

Comment: I need help to renounce a practice, I want to say that I will not let people give me tattoos(inserting pigments in the skin with tattoo machine)

Comment: @isitmeyolookinfor you could just say I will not let people tattoo me, or I will no longer get tattoos. Typically it is your choice, since you'd be paying for it (unless you're getting branded somehow).

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense, it's just a slightly strange metaphor. I would think it means something along the lines of "I won't allow other people to permanently change how I feel about myself."

Sometimes when you're told bad things about yourself often enough, even if they're untrue, it becomes an instinctive way of thinking about yourself -- the words have been metaphorically tattooed on you, but not so other people can see them.  They're only visible to you, yourself, as if they were tattooed on your mind rather than on your skin. I think that's what the author is saying, but I'd have to see the original context to know for sure.